# If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are zeros of the polynomial $4x^2 -x -4$, find the quadratic whose zeros are $\frac{1}{2\alpha}$ and $\frac{1}{2\beta}$.

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

I am utterly stuck at this question which I am sure has a simple solution, but I just can't seem to be able to see it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

> If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are zeros of the polynomial $4x^2 -x -4$, find the quadratic polynomial whose zeros are $\frac{1}{2\alpha}$ and $\frac{1}{2\beta}$.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you explain what you already tried ? It will be easier to help you. Thanks.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I have tried splitting the middle term to find the zeroes of the first quadratic, but thats the stage where I get stuck. Product being 16, and the sum being -1? I can't find the suitable numbers. Otherwise, plan was to find the zeros and input the values into the given fractions.

Comment: Do you know Viete's Theorem?

Comment: Hint: All you need is a simple substitution for $x$ in the equation $4x^2-x-4$. Look at the form(which is given to you) of the zeros for the new quadratic equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $$\left(x-\frac{1}{2 \alpha }\right) \left(x-\frac{1}{2 \beta }\right)=x^2-\frac 12  \left(\frac{1}{ \alpha }+\frac{1}{ \beta
   }\right)x+\frac{1}{4 \alpha  \beta }=x^2-\frac 12  \left(\frac{\alpha +\beta}{ \alpha\beta }
   \right)x+\frac{1}{4 \alpha  \beta }$$

Comment: Ah I see. Now it is a simple question of substitution! Thank you so much!

Comment: @AmanBhargava. You are very welcome !

Answer (score 1):

If $$4x^2-x-4=0$$ is true for $x=\alpha,\beta$, then $$4(2y)^{-2}-(2y)^{-1}-4=0$$ holds for $y=1/2\alpha,1/2\beta$.

You should be able to conclude.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=\frac{1}{2x}$. Then $4y^2-y-4$ cancels when $y=\alpha$ or $y=\beta$. But
$$y=\alpha \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{2x}=\alpha \Leftrightarrow x= \frac{1}{2\alpha}.$$
Now all you have to do is express $4y^2-y-4$ in terms of $x$. You will get a rational fraction, but it can only cancel when its numerator does; hence this numerator is your polynomial.

Answer (score -1):

You have $4x^2-x-4 = (x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$.  If you multiply the last bit out, you get expressions for $\alpha+\beta$ and $\alpha\beta$.  The quadratic you're looking for is $(x-1/2\alpha)(x-1/2\beta)$.  If you multiply this out and clear fractions, the expressions you found above should give you your answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I did not understand the " If you multiply this out and clear fractions", could you elaborate perhaps?

Comment: You multiply the expression and you'll have some fractions.  Multiply the whole business by $4\alpha\beta$ and the fractions will go away.  Your coefficients will be nice versions of $\alpha + \beta$ and $\alpha\beta$.

Comment: I found a nice answer to this question. But I really appreciate the effort put in by you. Thank you so much!